# Calculate the pearson coefficient between two lists

Tags: r, list, structure, correlation, pearson

I have two different lists (a and b) containing 626257 vectors, each vector containing 44 numeric entries. One list contains sample data and the other list serves as a reference. Now I want to calculate the pearson correlation between all the entries of both lists. I store the values in a variable (r).

The output of "r" does unfortunately only contain "NA" entries.

Here the code to generate two dummy lists.

```
a = replicate(626257,rep(10,44),simplify = FALSE)
b = replicate(626257,rep(3,44),simplify = FALSE)
```

And here the code to calculate the correlation.

```
r = lapply(seq_along(a), function(ind)cor(a[[ind]], b[[ind]]))
View(r)
```

Comment: Your vectors will have zero variance, try replacing them with random data, `rnorm(44)` for example.

Comment: What is your desired result? Do you want 626257 values or do you want one value (the correlation between all values in `a` and all values in `b`?

Comment: I can not replace the 44 value by rnorm(44). Because I want to have 44 entries per vector. But I tried this: rnorm(10) and rnorm(3). But now I have 440 and 132 entries per vector. I do not understand why. I want random numbers within the vectors but the number (626257) and length (44) of the vectors should not change.
In the end I would like to have 626257 correlation values.

Comment: The code in my answer (which includes `rnorm(44)`)  creates a vector with 44 normally distributed values - it is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mapply` to complete this task pretty easily. As AkselA pointed out, you first need to simulate data with some variance (using `rnorm(44)` instead of `rep, 10, 44)` for example). See below:

```r
a <- replicate(626257,rnorm(44),simplify = FALSE)
b <- replicate(626257,rnorm(44),simplify = FALSE)
r <- mapply(cor, a, b)
```

Comment: That was exactly I was looking for. Thank you